# Generate Menu From php array

Tags: php, html, menu

I am generating menu from php array

```
$MENU["HOME"] = array( 'enabled'=>true, 'text'=>'Home' ,'link'=> 'public/home' );
$MENU["SHOP"] = array( 'enabled'=>true, 'text'=>'Shop' ,'link'=> 'public/shop' );
```

and the code to generate the menu is

```
function show_menu(){

  $menu_string = '<ul>';

 foreach( $MENU as $item )
 {

    if( $item['enabled'] )
    {

       $menu_string .= '<li>'.$item['text'].'</li>';

    }

 }

echo $menu_string.'</ul>';
}
```

but now i have many levels of menu's as following ,so i changed my config to

```
$MENU["HOME"] = array
(
'parent'=>true, // parent == true ? show in top level menu : do not show in top level
'enabled'=>true,
'text'=>'Home',
'link'=> 'public/home',
'sub_modules' => array()   // empty sub modules means no sub menus need to display
);

 $MENU["SHOP"] = array
( 
'parent'=>true,
'enabled'=>true,
'text'=>'Shop',
'link'=> 'public/shop',
'sub_modules' => array('SALES') // SALES is a sub menu of SHOP,which is also configured as another module
);

$MENU["SALES"] = array
( 
'parent'=>FALSE, // PARENT = FALSE (this is a sub menu of SHOP)
'enabled'=>true,
'text'=>'Sales',
'link'=> 'public/shop/sales',
'sub_modules' => array('SALES_RETURN','SALES_REPORT') //have 2 sub menu's
);

$MENU["SALES_RETURN"] = array
( 
'parent'=>FALSE, 
'enabled'=>true,
'text'=>'Sales Return',
'link'=> 'public/shop/sales/return',
'sub_modules' => array() 
);

 $MENU["SALES_REPORT] = array
( 
'parent'=>FALSE, 
'enabled'=>true,
'text'=>'Sales Report',
'link'=> 'public/shop/sales/report',
'sub_modules' => array() 
);
```

now i cannot use the same function because menu is going deeper,

If `parent` is `true` then it means that that particular module/menu is enabled ,

how can i achieve this ? ( the menu may have sub modules , but sub modules may have some other menu's too,thats the problem  )

the expected result is

```
<UL>

 <li>Home</li>
 <li>
  Shop 
    <UL>   
         <LI>
           SALES 
           <UL>
               <LI>Sales Return</LI>
               <LI>Sales Report</LI>
           </UL>  
         </LI>
    </UL> 
 </li>

</UL>
```

Comment: you must use a recursive function or implement [RecursiveIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiterator.php) and iterate with [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php)

Comment: If you have multiple levels of what you had before a good solution would be to turn your old code into a recursive function.

Comment: @redreggae Thanks , but for some reasons i really need this to work on PHP4 too.

Answer (score 1):

tested, working...

```
<?php

    $MENU=array();

    $MENU["HOME"] = array
    (
    'parent'=>true, // parent == true ? show in top level menu : do not show in top level
    'enabled'=>true,
    'text'=>'Home',
    'link'=> 'public/home',
    'sub_modules' => array()   // empty sub modules means no sub menus need to display
    );

     $MENU["SHOP"] = array
    ( 
    'parent'=>true,
    'enabled'=>true,
    'text'=>'Shop',
    'link'=> 'public/shop',
    'sub_modules' => array('SALES') // SALES is a sub menu of SHOP,which is also configured as another module
    );

    $MENU["SALES"] = array
    ( 
    'parent'=>FALSE, // PARENT = FALSE (this is a sub menu of SHOP)
    'enabled'=>true,
    'text'=>'Sales',
    'link'=> 'public/shop/sales',
    'sub_modules' => array('SALES_RETURN','SALES_REPORT') //have 2 sub menu's
    );

    $MENU["SALES_RETURN"] = array
    ( 
    'parent'=>FALSE, 
    'enabled'=>true,
    'text'=>'Sales Return',
    'link'=> 'public/shop/sales/return',
    'sub_modules' => array() 
    );

     $MENU["SALES_REPORT"] = array
    ( 
    'parent'=>FALSE, 
    'enabled'=>true,
    'text'=>'Sales Report',
    'link'=> 'public/shop/sales/report',
    'sub_modules' => array() 
    );

    function show_menu(&$MENU,$subIndex=false){

        $menu_string = '<UL>';


        if(!$subIndex){
            foreach($MENU as $item)
            {
                if( $item['enabled']&&$item['parent'] )
                {
                    $_subString="";
                    if(!empty($item['sub_modules'])){
                        foreach($item['sub_modules'] as $sub){
                            $_subString .= show_menu($MENU,$sub);
                        }
                    }
                    $menu_string .= '<LI>'.$item['text'].$_subString.'</LI>';
                }
            }
        }else{
            if(@$MENU[$subIndex]['enabled']&&!@$MENU[$subIndex]['parent'])
            {
                $_subString="";
                if(!empty($MENU[$subIndex]['sub_modules'])){
                    foreach($MENU[$subIndex]['sub_modules'] as $sub){
                        $_subString .= show_menu($MENU,$sub);
                    }
                }
                $menu_string .= '<LI>'.$MENU[$subIndex]['text'].$_subString.'</LI>';
            }
        }

        return $menu_string.'</UL>';
    }

    echo show_menu($MENU);

?>
```

Comment: i checked it and found that there is a small problem , i tried to fix it ,the second level should be `<li>item<UL><li>item_sub1</li><li>item_sub2</li></ul></li>` instead of `<li>item<ul><li>item_sub1</li></ul><ul><li>item_sub2</li></ul></li>`

Answer (score 0):

this is quite easy to do with a recursive function, I'll give you a first version (non-tested):

```
function parse_menu($menu){
    echo "<li>".$menu['text']."</li>"
    if(!empty($menu['sub_modules'])){
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($menu['sub_modules'] as $e){
            parse_menu($menus_array[$e]); //or whatever you are calling the generic array
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
```

You should call for each $menus_array element that has no parent (level 0 of the tree).

Answer (score -1):

Just because the other two answers are not solutions to this question at all, I searched a few days in this topic and found pretty decent and efficient solution [there](https://www.copterlabs.com/build-menu-with-recursive-functions/). I am posting this because of other people reading this in the future and hope this will help anyone as well as it did to me. Also, the style of the array has to be changed as well. Read the whole post.

EDIT: 
This could be the array

```
$menu = array(
'about' => array(
'display' => 'About Us'),
'blog' => array(
'display' => 'Read Our Blog'),
'links' => array(
'display' => 'Recommended Links',
'sub' => array(
'products' => array(
'display' => 'High-Quality Products',
'url' => 'links/#products'),
'services' => array(
'display' => 'Helpful Services',
'url' => 'links/#services',
'sub' => array(
'local' => array(
'display' => 'Local Services',
'url' => 'links/#services_local'),
'online' => array(
'display' => 'Online Services',
'url' => 'links/#services_online')
)))),
'contact' => array(
'display' => 'Contact Us'
));
```

And this is the function. I tested it and it's working.

```
function buildMenu($menu_array, $is_sub = FALSE){
$attr =
(!$is_sub) ? ' id="menu"' : ' class="submenu"';
$menu = "<ul$attr>";
foreach($menu_array as $id => $properties) {        
foreach($properties as $key => $val) {
if (is_array($val)) {
$sub = buildMenu($val, TRUE);
}else{
$sub = NULL;
$$key = $val;
}}
if (!isset($url)) {
$url = $id;
}
$menu.="<li><a href=" . $url . ">$display</a>$sub</li>";
unset($url, $display, $sub);
}
return $menu . "</ul>";
}
```

Just call `echo buildMenu($menu);` somewhere in your code. Outputs this code which is expected:

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li><a href=about>About Us</a></li>
   <li><a href=blog>Read Our Blog</a></li>
   <li>
      <a href=links>Recommended Links</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
         <li><a href=links/#products>High-Quality Products</a></li>
         <li>
            <a href=links/#services>Helpful Services</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
               <li><a href=links/#services_local>Local Services</a></li>
               <li><a href=links/#services_online>Online Services</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href=contact>Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16875501)

Comment: @Blackbam - this link is 8 years+ old so I don't think it will broke anytime soon. But thanks, I will keep it in mind for the future. :)

Comment: that's how stackoverflow works: provide link as reference, but never post a link only answer.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre for real? Who in the world is down-voting and deleting good answers which actually could help somebody? If you are not happy with your life, you don't have to be that evil on people.

Comment: it's not a problem of being evil it's a problem of not polluting the site with link only answers. Please take a larger tour before giving your advice. You're new here. Check meta site, read the "how to post a good answer", etc.. In the meantime, you have corrected your answer so thank you.

Comment: (note that your post was flagged as "low quality", maybe by a bot, maybe by an user, but not me. You see, I'm not the one being evil. There's no evil here, just people who want to keep SO great.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre Man, I wanted to update the answer earlier, but it's hard on slow hotel WiFi on mobile device. You could just tell me and not go ahead and down-vote + delete.

Comment: Why did you think I downvoted? I didn't. I recommended deletion that's true. But since you edited, not sure it still holds. Why are you picking on me? Blackbam was the first one to vote for delete from "low quality answers" queue. I was just trying to help you with my comment. I guess next time I'll just vote and shut up.